# How to use ? keyword for string

Tags: c#, asp.net, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

I have a simple condition and want to implement it with `?:` keyword but compiler do't let me. this is the exact sample

```
// in asp page decleration
<ajaxtoolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender id="ftbeNumeric" runat="server" TargetControlID="textbox1" FilterType="Numbers" />
<asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" runat="server" />

// in code behind 
decimal x = textbox1.Text != string.IsNullOrEmpty ? Convert.ToDecimal(textbox1.Text) : 0;
```

I also try this

```
// in code behind 
decimal x = Convert.ToDecimal(textbox1.Text) != 0 ? Convert.ToDecimal(textbox1.Text) : 0;
```

bith of these sample face with error.

how to define this with `?:` keyword? and note that `textbox`.text` may be null.

Comment: As Oak said IsNullOrEmpty is not a property it's a static method.
It seems you want to convert a string to a decimal if it has a value (is not null or empty) which can lead to an InvalidCastException if value can not be cast to a decimal.Therefore I suggest using a more clear and safer method (like Anthony Pegram said).The advantage of this method is it shows what's intended to be done e.g.a default value has been chosen intentionally or a custom exception has been thrown

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider changing it to something like

```
decimal x;
if (!decimal.TryParse(textbox1.Text, out x))
{
    // throw an exception?
    // set it to some default value?
}
```

Of course, if you would like to throw an exception on an invalid/missing input, you could simply use the .Parse method instead and it would throw one for you. But using .TryParse would allow you to customize the exception's message or simply handle it another way, such as reprompting the user.

Answer (score 3):

`String.IsNullOrEmpty` is a method, not a field. So proper usage is `String.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox1.Text)`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with this statement

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox1.Text) ? 0 : Convert.ToDecimal(textbox1.Text);
```

Comment: That statement doesn't really *fix* it. In it, you're saying if there's nothing in the textbox, convert it to a decimal. Otherwise, make it 0. See a problem?

Comment: @Anthony - Actually I write ithere so thatI had a mistake - Thank you for your consideration. I correct it for new commers.